# Jenkins mail or telegram HTML build report

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, xunit, telegram-bot, test-reporting

I have a Jenkins project generating build / test reports.
Right now these reports are available within Jenkins, but I would like to mail or better yet, send them to a telegram bot that we have running.

I have been searching high and low but have been unable to find out how I would approach this, since I am not familiar with the Xunit format.

I have found this Jenkins plugin which seems to do partly what I want to do:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin

Also I have found and already enabled the following unofficial Jenkins Telegram bot plugin: https://github.com/devnull-tools/jenkins-notifier

Answer (score 0):

I've been finding out and apparently one can create a single bot on Telegram, however I use these plugins that are pretty good, one is Slack (https://plugins.jenkins.io/slack) and the other by Mail ( https://plugins.jenkins.io/email-ext).

I hope I can help you.
Greetings.